# How to check the completeness of JSON data

Tags: python, json

I get data in JSON from an API and it may be that the received data is not complete (= some fields are missing). I am not sure either that the structure of the data follows JSON standards.

The solution for the second problem is simple: I will `try:` to decode the JSON and act accordingly on `ValueError` and `TypeError` exceptions.

For the first problem, my solution would also be to

```
d = {'a': 1}
try:
    d['a']
    d['b']
    d['x']['shouldbethere']
except KeyError:
(...)
```

that is to list all the keys I need to have in the `dict` created from a successful JSON conversion.

This made me think that there may be **a method to declare the expected keys** (and possibly values types) and match the retrieved JSON against it, an unsuccessful match raising a specific exception?

Comment: [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org)? If you have known schema you may validate your JSON document against it using [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) package.

Comment: @Rogalski: this is exactly what I was looking for!  Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? I will just need to see if this allows to check for a subset of the returned data (the one i actually need, I do not care if the rest is present or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard way to validate JSON structure is to use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org).
Basic characteristics (quoted from official webpage) are:

> **JSON Schema:**
>
> - describes your existing data format
> - clear, human- and machine-readable documentation
> - complete structural validation, useful for
>
>   - automated testing
>   - validating client-submitted data

There is no built-in package to validate JSON object against schema, although you may use [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) from pypi.

Sample usage (paraphrased from official docs) may be:

```
import jsonschema

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "price": {"type": "number"},
        "name": {"type": "string"},
    },
}

jsonschema.validate({"name": "Eggs", "price": 34.99}, schema)
# No exception from line above - document is valid
jsonschema.validate({"name": "Eggs", "price": "Invalid"}, schema)
# ValidationError: 'Invalid' is not of type 'number'
```

Comment: This also works for partial descriptions (one does not need to describe the whole data set if only a few keys are needed)

Answer (score -1):

JSON parsers aren't terribly easy to use for error correction, so if the data isn't JSON I think it would be very difficult to apply any kind of auto-correction to allow you to parse it, so your solution for the invalid JSON is probably the most reasonable decision.

A function to verify that a dict contains a particular set of keys is relatively easy to implement. I'm not aware of any JSON object methods to perform that test, but given a JSON object `j` you could check it as follows (it might also be sensible to check that it's a dict, since JSON objects can also be of other types):

```
def has_all_keys(j, keylist):
    return all(key in j for key in keylist)
```

Using this interactively suggests is might work (in this example I rely on the fact that iteration over a string yields the individual characters, but obviously you will need a real list of string key values).

```
>>> has_all_keys({}, "abc")
False
>>> has_all_keys({'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}, "abc")
True
```

Comment: What about nested dictionaries as in the OP's example `d['x']['shouldbethere']`? And I think that `j` should be a dictionary - there is no such thing as  JSON object in Python.

Comment: Assuming top top-level keys pass, apply the same function to the dict value. I could attempt a recursive reformulation, but until the OP says this won't do, it's a YAGNI

Comment: OP _has_ said that. They want to check for nested dictionary keys such as `d['x']['shouldbethere']`, so it's not a case of YAGNI.

Comment: The YAGNI would be adding extra functionality when what I wrote up can be used to do the job. Feel free to edit my answer to provide that feature if you want, or write your own answer.

Comment: I'd agree with you if your answer actually did the job, but it doesn't handle the nested dictionaries in the OP's question. JSON schemas (the accepted answer) is the right way to do it.

Comment: And since that answer has been accepted I don't see any need to further elaborate mine

Comment: I'm not elaborating on your answer. I'm just refuting your consistently incorrect statements.